# To prove triangle is equilateral> given one equation and one combined equation.

Tags: linear-algebra

show that the lines $ x^2 - 4xy +y^2 $ and $x +y=3 $ form an equilateral trinagle . Also Find Area.

Here is what I have tried:
$ l1 =x+y=3 $
The combined equation is:
$ x^2 - 4xy + y^2 $
compare it with general formula :
$ ax^2 +2hxy+y^2  $
What to do next ? 
I could find the slope but how will that help ?

Comment: Did you mean $x^2−4xy+y^2=0$ ? Without the equals sign it is _not_ an equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $y = mx$ in the joint equation. That will produce auxiliary equation $$m^2 - 4m + 1 = 0$$

Solving this will give $$m = \dfrac{4 \pm \sqrt{4^2 - 4}}{2} = \dfrac{4 \pm 2\sqrt3}{2} = 2\pm \sqrt{3}$$

Let $m_1 = 2+\sqrt3, m_2 = 2-\sqrt3$

Gradient of $x+y = 1$ is $-1$, let $m_3 = -1$.

Use $\tan\theta = \left|\dfrac{m_a-m_b}{1+m_am_b}\right|$ for all $3$ pairs and prove that it is $\tan \dfrac\pi3 = \sqrt3$

$$\tan\theta_{m_1m_2} = \left|\dfrac{(2+\sqrt3)-(2-\sqrt3)}{1+(2+\sqrt3)(2-\sqrt3)}\right| = \left|\dfrac{2\sqrt3}{1+4-3}\right| = \sqrt3$$

$$\tan\theta_{m_1m_3} = \left|\dfrac{2+\sqrt3+1}{1-2-\sqrt3}\right| = \left|\dfrac{\sqrt3(1+\sqrt3)}{-(1+\sqrt3)} \right| = \sqrt3$$

$\theta_{m_2m_3}$ can be calculated similarly.

Comment: What is auxiliary equation ?

Comment: Auxiliary equation is the equation in $m$, where $m = \dfrac{y}{x}$. Here the auxiliary equation for given pair of lines is $m^2 - 4m + 1= 0$

Comment: i put y=mx in the combined eqaution?

Comment: Yes, if you do it, you will get the auxiliary equation. Note that this works because the given pair of lines passes through origin, so both lines are of the form $y = mx$

Comment: how do you know that the given pair of lines pass through the origin ?

Comment: Put $x = y = 0$, it satisfies the given equation. Alternatively, the curve passes through origin iff there is no constant term.

Comment: ok so 
$x^2 -4x(mx) +(mx)^2$ like this ?

Comment: Yes, and then you can cancel $x^2$s.

Comment: How do i do so ?

Comment: $x^2 + 4mx^2 +m^2x^2 = 0 \implies x^2( m^2 -4m+1) = 0 \implies m^2 -4m + 1 = 0$ which is the auxiliary equation which I got.

Comment: oh you divided the equation by $ x^2$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17436/discussion-between-taninamdar-and-iffat).

Comment: i need to finish signing up first

Comment: @taninandar I also need to find the area of this triangle. How can i find that?

Answer (score 1):

If the angle between $y=mx$ and $x+y=3\iff y=-x+3$ is $60^\circ,$

$$\left|\frac{m-(-1)}{1+m(-1)}\right|=\tan60^\circ=\sqrt3$$

$$\iff\frac{m+1}{m-1}=\pm\sqrt3\iff(m+1)^2=3(m-1)^2\iff m^2-4m+1=0$$

Setting $m=\dfrac yx\implies y^2-4xy+x^2=0$

Comment: Certainly better than my solution! :-)

Comment: @Iffat, How about this?